# Generating a link after uploading a file

Tags: php, html

edit: To sum it all up, I wanted to see how to make a website generate a link after a file has been uploaded.

First time posting here, I hope I'm not breaking the rules by asking this, haha.

I'm trying to set up an upload function on my website by following the [tutorial on tizag,](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) but I can't seem to figure out how to make it that after uploading, the user is presented with a link to the file (like how you would upload something to imgur and receive a short link like this imgur.com/k4FzF6W ).

Thank you for your help! I'm very new to php and I'm not the best at code in general.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Micheal_B Thanks! I added a clearer statement up top, I hope that works. :)

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on if you have the button to upload and stuff BUT here is just the basics of it, since I don't know what your code is.

```
$fileupload = uploadedfilenamehere;
function grabLink() { 
echo "site.com/".$fileupload;
}
```

Which would return:

"site.com/uploadedfilenamehere"

And if you need to have a directiory just change this:

```
echo "site.com/dir/".$fileupload;
```